# Как вытащить элементы из xml ответа?

Tags: xml, php

У меня есть ответ вот такого типа:

```
<yandex-mobile-info>
<name>One Touch C651</name><!-- название модели телефона -->
<vendor>Alcatel</vendor><!-- название производителя телефона -->
<device-class>midp2ss</device-class><!-- класс устройства -->
<device-class-desc>Java MIDP2 (small)</device-class-desc><!-- описание класса устройства -->
<screenx>128</screenx><!-- разрешение экрана в пикселах по ширине -->
<screeny>160</screeny><!-- разрешение экрана в пикселах по высоте -->
<java><!-- контейнер для Java-параметров -->
    <cam-access>1</cam-access><!-- есть ли у Java-приложений доступ к камере устройства -->
    <fs-access>1</fs-access><!-- есть ли у Java-приложений доступ к файловой системе устройства -->
    <certificate-prefix></certificate-prefix> <!-- префикс Java-сертификата -->
    <iconsize>18x18</iconsize><!-- размер значка Java-приложения -->
</java> 
</yandex-mobile-info>
```

Вопрос: как мне из него вытащить то, что заключено в теги device-class? Помогите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php).

Answer (score 1):

Можно так же через [DOM](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php), он чуть медленнее SimpleXML, но более гибок и близок по принципу к JS DOM